# Jmeter timer - Increase value with running time

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter to generate HTTP requests. I want to add a timer which decreases in value with the running time. I have studied BeanShell timer but was unable to find the required parameter.

Comment: There is a counter variable ${__counter()} which increases with time. I am using constant timer. I want to evaluate like  5000-${__counter}   but it is not working. What is the correct format to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some variable holding some value and would like to increment that value the easiest way will be using [__intSum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum)

However if you still want Beanshell it would be something like:

```
int currentValue = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("myVar"));
int newValue = currentValue + 1;
vars.put("myVar", String.valueOf(newValue));
```

The above Beanshell code increments `${myVar}` variable value by 1 each time it's called. `vars` - is a shorthand to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance which provides read/write access to JMeter Variables.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article to learn more about using Beanshell test elements in JMeter test.